# Filter out Indexes in List

Tags: elm

I need to filter out empty positions from this 2D List but have only been able to get a list back of indexes *after* it's been filtered already which means the indexes no longer match up to the indexes these positions had when they were once part of the 2D array.

```
list :: List Char
list = ['X',' ',' ','O','O',' ','X',' ',' ']

openPositionIndexes = List.filter (\pos -> pos == empty) list
    |> (List.indexedMap (\i pos -> i))
-- [0,1,2,3,4] : List Int
```

what I need is `[1, 2, 5, 7, 8]` as the openPositionIndexes not `[0,1,2,3,4]` because those indexes are wrong, they're based on the *filtered* `list` result, not the original indexes found in `list` array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll have to run it through `List.indexedMap` first, then save the index along with the value for later use. Here I pack them together in a tuple:

```
openPositionIndexes =
    list
        |> List.indexedMap (\i cell -> ( i, cell ))
        |> List.filter (\( _, cell ) -> cell == empty)
        |> List.map Tuple.first
```

Or using a record:

```
openPositionIndexes =
    list
        |> List.indexedMap (\i cell -> { index = i, cell = cell })
        |> List.filter (\{ cell } -> cell == empty)
        |> List.map .index
```

Comment: thanks can you explain both `( i, cell )` and  `( _, cell )` and how Tuple works here in relation to this example, I'm new to Elm.

Comment: A tuple is essentially just a record without the labels. Just a box with two (or more, but typically just two) values in it. You can get the values out by using `Tuple.first` or `Tuple.second` for each position respectively, or by deconstruct it using the same syntax you use to construct it, just like with lists and records. Here I deconstruct it by assigning the first value to `_`, which ignores it, and the second value to `cell`

Comment: More here: https://elmprogramming.com/tuple.html SO isn't a great place for tutorials.

Comment: I've updated the answer with an example using a record instead, which is just a little bit more verbose.